# How to convert python list to lxml.etree._Element

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, lxml

p[0] is a lxml.etree._Element. When I use [2:] on p[0], it becomes a list, so I cannot use XPath again. So how can I remove 2 front elements in p[0] without turning it to a list?

```
root = etree.HTML(res.text)
p = root.xpath('//div[@id="J"]/p')
p = p[0][2:].xpath('string(.)')
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: Do you want to get text from paragraphs (starting from third) that all are children of `div[@id="J"]`?

Comment: I want to get from the third to the end, so I use [2:]

Comment: Can you edit the question and show what `p` looks like?

Comment: p is just [p[0]] and p[0] is a lxml.etree._Element.